# Hide the button in first record only - laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have 3 buttons in my action column. I wanted to hide the two buttons and left the other one after checking the user role in the system (if admin or user). My problem is that I can only hide the two buttons in the first record that I have. The rest is still the same. How can I solve this?

This is my function in javascript

```
function load_datatable(id){

            var flag_color;
            $.ajax({
                url: "loadInquiriesData",
                type: "POST",
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success:function(data){
                inquire_t.dataTable().fnClearTable();
                $.each(data,function(key,value){
                    switch(value.flag){
                        case 'Forwarded as Direct Inquiry': flag_color = '#0000ff'; break;
                        case 'New': flag_color = '#0000ff'; break;
                        case 'Open': flag_color = '#000000'; break;
                        case 'On-Hold': flag_color = '#ff0000'; break;
                        case 'Attended': flag_color = '#27ae60'; break;
                        case 'Closed': flag_color = '#000000'; break;
                        case 'Pending': flag_color = '#ff0000'; break;
                    }
                    inquire_t.dataTable().fnAddData([
                        value.refNumber,
                        value.client,
                        value.details,
                        value.dateCreated,
                        value.reply,
                        value.acknowledgeBy,
                        value.category,
                        "<font color='"+flag_color+"'><strong>"+value.flag+"</strong></font>",
                        "<button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' id='openbtn' value='"+value.refNumber+"'name='"+value.flag+"'> <span class='fa fa-eye' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Open Ticket'></span></button>"+
                        " <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' id='btn-close' value='"+value.refNumber+"' name='"+value.flag+"'> <span class='fa fa-close' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Close Ticket'></span></button>"+
                        "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-envelope' data-toggle ='modal' data-target='#threadmessage'></button>"
                        // " href='message/thread'
                        // 
                    ]);//datatable
                });//each

                //update_datatable();
                }//success
            });//ajax

            //get role
            //console.log(id);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getUserRoles',
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")},
                data: id,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(role){
                    $.each(role, function(key, value){
                        var hasRole = value.hasRole;
                        // console.log(role);
                        if (hasRole == 'BSI') {
                            var hidden = false;
                            document.getElementById('openbtn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                            document.getElementById('btn-close').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                        }else{
                            //console.log('with action');
                            // Get the column API object - get Action column
                            var column = table.columns(8);
                            // Toggle the visibility - show Action column for admin
                            column.visible(column.visible());
                        }//else
                    });//each
                }//success
            });//ajax 
        }// load_datatable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using ID attribute which should be unique in whole document. Try to use Class attribute instead & everything will be ok.

```
<button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs openbtn'...
<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-close'...
```

And:

```
$('.openbtn, .btn-close').hide();
```

If you want to use vanilla javascript:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('openbtn'), function(el) {
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

Hope this helps.
Also check [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really/127180#127180) for detail explanation.

Comment: Hi Nghia Dau thank you for your answer. I did what you told me but this error occur             Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (showInquiries:628)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (showInquiries:616)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Thank you very much Nghia Dau. It finally works now :)